# No setter method in boost local_date_time?

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost date_time library to develop a filtering scheme in my application. Say I have 10000 records and each contain a timestamp (milliseconds in UTC). I want to convert this timestamp to a given timezone using boost and then return the time part in milliseconds. I am using the following code snippet :

```
local_date_time localDate(pt, tz_ptr);
return localDate.local_time().time_of_day().total_milliseconds();
```

In this code, pt is a ptime object created from timestamp (in milliseconds). The time zone pointer is constant for all 10000 records. Therefore, it is wasteful to create a local_date_time object at every iteration. If possible, I want to reuse this object. I was looking for a method like :

```
localDate.set(ptime pt);
```

But I could not find anything like that. Anyone know if something like this exist?

Comment: I think there is probably too little code here to probably help, but if I understand correctly you wish to return `localDate.local_time().time_of_day().total_milliseconds()`, but in order to do so you need to make `localDate` from `pt` (which is constant). Why isn't `localDate` just a member of a class, and when constructed it initialises `pt` from the milliseconds and passes it to `localDate`, then the function can just return the member?

Comment: There does not seem to be a method like the above.  How does your filter work?  Maybe it would be easier to convert the query time rather than the stored data?

Comment: @Tas : sorry if it was not very clear. Each record has a timestamp in UTC. I need to convert to to a given timezone. In order to do that, I basically have to create a local_date_time object in each iteration of the loop and return the time part. My question is whether I can create a single local_date_time object. In each iteration of the loop, I should set the timestamp as ptime to this local_date_time and convert it at appropriate timezone. The problem is I did not find a setter method for local_date_time.

Comment: @Robert : If there is a timestamp in UTC in each record and I need to find out a set of records that falls in date range or something and in a given timezone, I will have to convert each UTC timestamp to given timezone. I am not sure how I can avoid that.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, what I'm suggesting is all the queries about a particular time zone could be converted to an equivalent query about UTC time.  For instance if I was talking about 9 a.m. - 12 p.m. PT, then I am talking about 5:00 p.m. - 8 p.m. UTC.  This way you can preprocess all your stored data to handle queries only about UTC time and the only time zone conversion that has to be made is on the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Therefore, it is wasteful to create a local_date_time object at every iteration"

Have you looked at the emitted assembly? I think you're prematurely optimizing.

The idea of ptime is to be "immutable value-type". Same goes for local_date_time. The complicating factor here is that the library designers have modeled timezone instances with shared ownership (for good reasons).

This is actually the only part you should worry about. I'd calculate the timezone offset up-front, just once and then just forego the local_date_time altogether.

> **CAVEAT** If you do, make sure you account for dst/non-dst dates! The offset will vary. I'm not sure whether boost/the OS even take historical time zone changes into account.
>
> It's probably best to use Boost DateTime's zone implementation and just do the raw conversions without the help of local_date_time

Another way to sidestep a lot of complexity is to consider using

- `boost::date_time::c_local_adjustor<ptime>`
- `boost::date_time::local_adjustor<ptime>`

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.local_utc_conversion

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used local_adjustor and it performs better than local_date_time. One problem I see is that we have to specify offset in hours along dst/no dst option.